# Nested Figure Numbers in Quarto HTML document

Tags: css, r, r-markdown, rstudio, quarto

I'm creating an HTML Quarto document, where I have chapter numbers (e.g. Chapter 1), and then sections (e.g. 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, etc.), and sometimes sub-sections numbered, for example, 1.1.1, 1.1.2, 2.1.1. 2.1.2, 2.4.3, etc.  Within the sections or subsections, I frequently display figure/listing output and am automatically applying caption numbering, but the caption numbers seem to repeat the section number or subsection number (e.g. Figure 1.1 for figures in Section 1.1).  How can I start figure/listing caption numbers as X.Y1.Y2.Z, where X is the chapter number, Y1 is the section number, Y2 is the (optional) subsection number, and Z is sequentially numbered and restarts in each section or subsection.

When I currently apply listing/figure numbering, this creates the following output:

> Chapter 1
>
> 1.1 My First Section
>
> Figure 1.1
>
> Chapter 2
>
> 2.1  My First Section in Chapter 2
>
> 2.2  My Second Section in Chapter 2
>
> 2.2.1 My First Subsection in Section 2, Chapter 2
>
> Figure 2.2
>
> Figure 2.3

Instead, what I'd like is the following:

> Chapter 1
>
> 1.1 My First Section
>
> Figure 1.1.1
>
> Chapter 2
>
> 2.1  My First Section in Chapter 2
>
> 2.2  My Second Section in Chapter 2
>
> 2.2.1 My First Subsection in Section 2, Chapter 2
>
> Figure 2.2.1.1
>
> Figure 2.2.1.2

Does anyone have any idea how I can change the default numbering to nest the figure number into the section or subsection number?  If this can't be accomplished directly in Quarto, is there a way to accomplish this with CSS, perhaps?

Thanks.